# How do I use React hooks in my component library?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-hooks, next.js

I'm currently creating a component library which is included in a Nextjs project via NPM link and having a hard time getting it to consistently load without errors. The latest one is

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons

This is a Typescript component, but as far as I can tell, what I've done is okay but it's just not playing sport. Here's the code:

```
        import React, { useEffect } from "react";
        import { FlagIcon } from "react-flag-kit";

        const LanguageSwitcher = () => {
            useEffect(() => {
                alert('Yo!');
            })
            return (
                <div className="w-full justify-end">
                    <button>
                        <div className="flex items-center">
                            <FlagIcon code="GB" /> <span className="block ml-2">English</span>
                        </div>
                    </button>
                </div>
            )
        }

        export default LanguageSwitcher
```

This is then being imported into another component in the library and then imported into the Nextjs page. Which is where the error is showing up.

I'm not sure if it's a webpack or typescript compiling issue, tried all the different targets I can think of, tried googling all sorts of things but nothing seems relevant to my situation. It might not even be a React issue but one with Typescript and Webpack, but my exposure to those is very new.

My webpack config:

```
        var path = require('path');
        module.exports = {
          entry: './src/index.ts',
          devtool: "source-map",
          output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
            filename: 'index.js',
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
          },
          module: {
            rules: [
              {
                test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
              },
              {
                enforce: "pre",
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "source-map-loader"
              }
            ]
          },
          resolve: {
            extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
          }
        };
```

My `tsconfig.json`

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "build",
        "module": "esnext",
        "target": "es6",
        "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2016", "es2017"],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowJs": false,
        "jsx": "react",
        "declaration": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
      },
      "include": ["src"],
      "exclude": ["node_modules", "build"]
    }
```

Any pointers or help would be really appreciated!

I also tried reverting everything back to vanilla JS and the problem persists, so I think it might be webpack related?

**Edit**

Here is my full package.json file and also what Nextjs has

```
{
  "name": "some/package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "build/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "start": "webpack --watch --mode=development",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.10.2",
    "webpack": "^4.41.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    // ...
    "@types/react": "^16.9.5",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.1",
    "react": "16.10.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.2",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9"
  }
}
```

```
    "react": "16.10.2",
    "react-dom": "16.10.2"
```

Comment: It's not typescript or webpack, its react talking about wrong hook usage

Comment: wich versions of `react` and `react-dom` are you using?

Comment: Currently using `16.10.2` for Next and the library.

Comment: maybe this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58365151/hooks-error-invalid-hook-call-using-nextjs-or-reactjs-on-windows

Comment: Thanks for the link, although this is on Mac so I don't think it applies :/

Comment: you using 16.10.2 for both react and react-dom  ?

Comment: I believe so, I've posted my package.json file and the relevant part that Nextjs has

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React hooks in react library giving Invalid hook call error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56021112/react-hooks-in-react-library-giving-invalid-hook-call-error)

Comment: Duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56021112/react-hooks-in-react-library-giving-invalid-hook-call-error, though the answer on this web page is better (more concise) in my opinion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out this was due to issues with the symlinked react in the component library

https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#duplicate-react

Fixed by running the steps in the link:

```
npm link ../myapp/node_modules/react // Run within the component library
```

Comment: This would work, but how do I make it that users of my component library don't have to manually run this link script every time they install the library?

Comment: @DanielDon This doesn't need to be the case. when you publish your package, the package should be able to use react installed by the users of your component. Only when testing your component locally using `npm link`, you need to direct the package to use `react` installed in your non-package app.

Answer (score 0):

Was facing the same issue. However, the component library is not owned by me, hence had to things out using this [dependency resolution by 'Yarn'](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/)

This was my initial dependency tree

```
project
|- componentLibrary
|  |- react@16.10
|  |- react-dom@16.10
|- react@17.0.1
|- react-dom@17.0.1
```

added the following snippet in my package.json

```
"resolutions": {
  "componentLibrary/react": "17.0.1",
  "componentLibrary/react-dom": "17.0.1"
},
```

which resolved my dependencies to the project's `react` and `react-dom`.

Comment: Did the package.json belong to the component library or the react project?