# I keep getting invalid hook calls when I try to run my server with next.js, but when someone else clones my repo it renders fine on theirs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Like the title says, I'm building an app that renders initially with a simple login form made with React hooks, with a bare bones layout component sandwiching the form. When I run npm run dev, localhost:3000 tells me that I'm using an invalid hook call. I've had a couple of people check over the code and they couldn't see anything wrong with it, and they were able to clone the master branch of my repo and ran the server without any problems, so I'm pretty sure that the code itself isn't the problem. I'm not sure how to replicate the issue either, since other people aren't getting the error when they run the server, it's just on my system. Can anyone advise on what I can do to figure this out?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Router from 'next/router';

//makes the request to the db to verify usename/password and stores data to localstorage
const signInAPI = async user => {
  return axios
    .post('/api/login', {
      username: user.username,
      password: user.password
    })
    .then(response => {
      localStorage.setItem('userToken', response.data.token)
      localStorage.setItem('name', response.data.name)
      localStorage.setItem('authLevel', response.data.authLevel)
      localStorage.setItem('id', response.data.id)
      return response.data
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
}

const SignIn = function() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    username: '',
    password: ''
  })

  const handleInputChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target
    const newData = {
      [name]: value
    }
    setData({ ...data, ...newData}) 
  }

  const handleFormSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const user = {
      username: data.username,
      password: data.password
    }

    signInAPI(user).then(res => {
      if(res) {
        Router.push('.home')
      }
    })
  }

  return (
    <div className="ui middle aligned center aligned grid">
      <div className="column">
        <h2 className="ui image header">
          <div className="content">
          Sign-in to your account
          </div>
        </h2>
      <form className="ui large form">
        <div className="ui stacked segment">
          <div className="field">
            <div className="ui left icon input">
              <i className="user icon"></i>
              <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" value={data.username} onChange={handleInputChange} />
            </div>
          </div>
        <div className="field">
          <div className="ui left icon input">
            <i className="lock icon"></i>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value={data.password} onChange={handleInputChange} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="ui fluid large submit button" onClick={handleFormSubmit}>Login</div>
      </div>

      <div className="ui error message"></div>

      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
  )

};

export default SignIn
```

Comment: This kind of sounds similar to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58365151/hooks-error-invalid-hook-call-using-nextjs-or-reactjs-on-windows

Comment: @AlexK that was the issue exactly! The fix worked perfectly, thanks so much for the assist!