# Next Unhandled runtime error. No router instance found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I was making a portfolio in Next and i made just a header to show in all pages by putting it on _app.js, just that, never touched the _document.js. This is the error:

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: No router instance found.
You should only use "next/router" inside the client side of your app.
.next\static\chunks\fallback\main.js (116:10) @ getRouter

```
  114 |       'No router instance found.\n' +
  115 |       'You should only use "next/router" inside the client side of your app.\n'
> 116 |     throw new Error(message)
      |          ^
  117 |   }
  118 |   return singletonRouter.router
  119 | }
```

Here's the _app.js code

```
import Header from '../components/Header'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      <style jsx global>{`
        *{
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        body{
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          font-family: 'Epilogue'
        }
      `}</style>
    </>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

Comment: Please show the code of your `_app.js` file or any file that uses router.

Comment: Please show the code that references next/router. That's where the issue is

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem:

[Hooks error: Invalid Hook Call using NextJS or ReactJS on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58365151/hooks-error-invalid-hook-call-using-nextjs-or-reactjs-on-windows)

I was in "d/projects/..." instead of "d/Projects/...".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when running your NextJS project that you are in the correctly cased filepath.
My problem was that I was in the directory "react/next-project" instead of "React/next-project".