# useState not working in next js with material ui drawer

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js, use-state, drawer

useState not working. I have searched for a solution I checked many forms like https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7626 , https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/17592 ,
[Hooks error: Invalid Hook Call using NextJS or ReactJS on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58365151/hooks-error-invalid-hook-call-using-nextjs-or-reactjs-on-windows) , some people seem to suggest that it can be solved by removing a node module that they did not mention the name of, others says it works if they change their webpack configurations but i have never used webpack and couldn't find they mentioned so I am stuck.

I was implementing material ui's drawer, i have created a drawer component and imported it.

**Nav.jsx:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'React'
import SignedOutLinks from "./Links/SignedOutLinks"
import { AppBar, Toolbar } from "@material-ui/core"
import MenuBtn from "./Links/MenuBtn"
import Logo from "./Links/Logo"
import CategoryBtn from "./Links/CategoryBtn"
import ShoppingCartBtn from "./Links/ShoppingCartBtn"
import LanguageBtn from "./Links/LanguageBtn"
import DarkModeBtn from "./Links/DarkModeBtn"
import NotificationBtn from "./Links/NotificationBtn"
import SignedIn from "./Links/SignedIn"
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Search from "./Search/Search"
import { useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import useMediaQuery from '@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery';
import Drawer from './Drawer/Drawer'

const signedIn = true

const Nav = () => {
  const [isOpened, setIsOpened] = useState(false)
  const theme = useTheme()
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("sm"))

  const handleDrawerToggle = () => {
    setIsOpened(!isOpened)
  }

  return (
    <AppBar color="transparent" elevation={0} >
      <Toolbar>
        {
           !isMobile?
            <Grid
            container
            direction="row"
            justify="space-between"
            alignItems="center"
            spacing={10}
            >
              <Grid item container spacing={5} xs={4} justify="flex-start" wrap="nowrap">
                <Grid item>
                  <Logo/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                  <CategoryBtn />
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={4}>
                <Search />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item container xs={4} justify="flex-end" wrap="nowrap">
                  <ShoppingCartBtn />
                  <LanguageBtn />
                  <DarkModeBtn />
                  <NotificationBtn />
                  {signedIn? <SignedIn /> : <SignedOutLinks />}
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          :
          <div>
            <Drawer isOpened={isOpened} />
            <Grid
              container
              direction="row"
              justify="space-around"
              spacing={10}
            >
              <Grid item container xs={4} justify="flex-start">
                <MenuBtn handleClick={handleDrawerToggle} />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item Container xs={4} justify="center" style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
                <Grid item>
                  <Logo />
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item container xs={4} justify="flex-end">
                <ShoppingCartBtn />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </div>
        }
        
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  )
}

export default Nav
```

**Drawer.jsx:**

```
import { Drawer as MUIDrawer} from '@material-ui/core'
import { List, ListItem,ListItemText, ListItemIcon } from '@material-ui/core'
import NotificationsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Notifications';
import TranslateIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Translate';
import Brightness4Icon from '@material-ui/icons/Brightness4';
import LocalShippingIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LocalShipping';
import AccountCircleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle';
import BusinessIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Business';
import ExitToAppIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExitToApp';
import ChatBubbleOutlineIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChatBubbleOutline';
import CategoryIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Category';

function Drawer({isOpened}) {
    const items = [
        {
            text: user.userName,
            icon: <AccountCircleIcon />
        },
        {
            text: "Categories",
            icon: <CategoryIcon />
        },
        {
            text: "Language",
            icon: <TranslateIcon />
        },
        {
            text: "Mode",
            icon: <Brightness4Icon />
        },
        {
            text: "Notifications",
            icon: <NotificationsIcon />
        },
        {
            text: "Orders",
            icon: <LocalShippingIcon />
        },
        {
            text: "Are You a Seller?",
            icon: <BusinessIcon />
        },
        {
            text: "Messages",
            icon: <ChatBubbleOutlineIcon />
        },
        {
            text: "Logout",
            icon: <ExitToAppIcon />
        }
    ]

    return (
        <div>
            <MUIDrawer open={isOpened}>
                <List>
                    {
                        items.map(item => {
                        return (
                            <ListItem button key={item.text} >
                                {item.icon && <ListItemIcon>{item.icon}</ListItemIcon>}
                                <ListItemText primary={item.text} />
                            </ListItem>
                        )
                        })
                    }
                </List>
            </MUIDrawer>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Drawer
```

**Note it was working fine until i coded the Drawer, also useState is imported at the very beginning ing so i didn't forget to import it**

[image: Error]

***Edit:***

Folder Structure in next.js

[image]

**index.js:**

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'

import Nav from '../Components/Navbar/Nav'

export default function Home() {  
  return (
    <>
    <Head>
    <meta name="description" content="Everything for everyone. TRNC E-commerce website focused on a huge variety of categories from fashion to electronics. Order now and get your product delivered." />
    </Head>
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Nav />
    </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you show where/how you are using `Nav`?

Comment: I'd recommend just deleting the entire node_modules folder and then running "npm install" again to see if that has any effect.

Comment: I have added the folder an image of my folder structure with the code inside index.js . I have also deleted the node_modules and reinstalled it but it still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Its finally working, however I couldn't find the problem. I solved it by literaly creating a new component called Nav2 that i copied the same code from the original Nav component from and voila it worked, i deleted the old Nav component and renamed Nav2 to Nav and it kept working.

Note: i found that i forgot to import useContext in the drawer as user is an deconstructed object that is sent from _app.js so i added

const { user } = useContext(UserContext)

to the beginning of the component function